# Synchronize n Threads with only using Semaphore and/or mutex in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, semaphore, synchronize

We're studying for our test next week, and have been given an exercise from our teacher, and we just don't see the solution:

How to synchronize `n` threads, so that all `n` threads wait at a specific location and only continue with their "work" together when all `n` threads have reached that location?

We're allowed to use Mutex and Semaphore constructs. The solution should be easy, but we just cant find the answer.

Comment: Hint: what you are looking for is called a `barrier`. Pro hint: try writing some code yourself, and if you don't succeed, show us your effort and ask specific questions on how to solve specific, pinpointed problems.

Comment: If you are using the pthreads library for your threading, it has functions for working with barriers. Otherwise, you can implement a barrier using a mutex with a condition variable. Have a look at [Synchronization, Part 6: Implementing a barrier](https://github.com/angrave/SystemProgramming/wiki/Synchronization,-Part-6:-Implementing-a-barrier), and [Barriers](https://locklessinc.com/articles/barriers/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a big hint. You need 2 semaphores, both with `N` flags. You can solve this with an extra thread. The key is that you can call `down()` on a semaphore multiple times. e.g. If you call `down()` on a semaphore 8 times, you need all 8 `up()`'s before you can continue.

```
// an additional thread (not one of the N)
void trigger(Semaphore* workersCollect, Semaphore* workersRelease, int n)
{
    while(true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            workersCollect->down();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            workersRelease->up();
    }
}

// Prototype for the "checkpoint" function (exercise for the reader)
void await(Semaphore* workersCollect, Semaphore* workersRelease);
```

You can also solve it without the extra thread, by using more complicated state checking.

This design has a drawback. If a worker finishes its work extremely quickly, it can grab more than one task (while another thread ends up not running at all). This is fine if you have a threadpool kind of design, but bad if, say, each thread is supposed to work on it's own distinct section of a dataset.

To fix that, you need a semaphore per thread. Something akin to

```
Semaphore workerRelease[N];
```

but being careful to avoid false sharing. (You don't want more than 1 semaphore on a cache line.)